# Making an element fullscreen within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, html5-fullscreen

I'm working on a browser extension that allows me to modify content of other websites.

I know about `allowfullscreen` and how to make an element within an `iframe` appear fullscreen and take up the entire viewport. But, in this question, I want to find out how I can coerce an element to go fullscreen *within* an iframe.

**Scenario**:
Websites like [HBO](https://play.hbonow.com/page/urn:hbo:page:home), use  `position: absolute` on nearly every element in their page including the `video` element. When you try to fullscreen a video on their page, they determine the size of the viewport and scale elements accordingly by changing several nodes' `width` and `height` properties. This, when combined with hiding of unnecessary elements gives users a good fullscreen experience. As a result of their approach, it is extremely difficult to modify the CSS of these elements  by hand.

Setting `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;` on the `video` element doesn't really work as, at the very least, you would also need to style the video's controls.

Is it be possible to allow an element to go 'fullscreen' but only  within the confines of an iframe? Please note that the website's Javascript code must execute as though it is successfully switching to fullscreen, but just confined to within the `iframe`.

Comment: please create a code snippet. thanks

Comment: You can do it from the location of code files of content inside iframe. If you don't have control over the iframe content, then you can't do this.

Comment: @XenioGracias I'm not sure how I can create a useful code snippet. To alter content of arbitrary websites, you need to use a browser extension. Even with a browser extension, the question deals with whether something is achievable. Specifically, if it is possible to fullscreen an element within an iframe. I'm not sure what I would put into code snippet in this scenario..

Comment: _“Is it be possible to allow an element to go 'fullscreen' but only within the confines of an iframe?”_ - I don’t think so. After all, it does that not even do that in your “normal” document, when no iframe is involved - it does not stay confined to the dimensions of your “full” top window instance in that case either … that is _the point_ of fullscreen mode, to ignore the confines of whatever the current window dimensions are.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the body has default margins in most of the browsers. You should try this code in the page with `ifrmae`:

```
* {
   margin:0;
}
```

or

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```